# Vue Apollo cannot get parameters into mutation to not be null

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, graphql-js, vue-apollo

I am using Vue3 and Apollo Vue v4 using composable API.

I have the following mutation

```
const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values) => {
  const res = createItemMutation({
    description: "Test description",
    title: "Test Title",
    endsAt: new Date(),
  });
});

const {
  loading,
  error,
  mutate: createItemMutation,
  onDone,
} = useMutation<Maybe<Item>, MenuItemInput>(gql`
  mutation CreateItem($input: MenuItemInput!) {
    createAuctionItem(input: $input) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`);

onDone((result) => {
  router.push("/details/" + result.data?.id);
});
</script>
```

And here is the error I am getting

```
index.ts:71 Uncaught (in promise) Error: In argument "input": Expected type "MenuItemInput!", found null.
Variable "input": Expected non-null, found null.
```

Here are my generated types

```
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;
export type Exact<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
export type MakeOptional<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
  [SubKey in K]?: Maybe<T[SubKey]>;
};
export type MakeMaybe<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & {
  [SubKey in K]: Maybe<T[SubKey]>;
};
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
  DateTime: any;
};

export type Item = {
  __typename?: "Item";
  description?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>;
  endsAt?: Maybe<Scalars["DateTime"]>;
  id?: Maybe<Scalars["ID"]>;
  title?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>;
};

export type MenuItemInput = {
  description: Scalars["String"];
  endsAt: Scalars["DateTime"];
  title: Scalars["String"];
};

export type RootMutationType = {
  __typename?: "RootMutationType";
  createAuctionItem?: Maybe<Item>;
};

export type RootMutationTypeCreateAuctionItemArgs = {
  input: MenuItemInput;
};

export type RootQueryType = {
  __typename?: "RootQueryType";
  listItems?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Item>>>;
  popularItems?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Item>>>;
};

export type RootQueryTypeListItemsArgs = {
  limit?: Maybe<Scalars["Int"]>;
};
```

The onsubmit is called from a form

```
    <form
      @submit="onSubmit"
    >
```

I am having 2 issues, I cannot properly type my Graphql mutations and queries (using typescript) and the other one is the error mentioned above. I am using the same code as the docs so not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the type has to be

```
useMutation<Maybe<Item>, {item: MenuItemInput}>
```